# Unexplained underscore in name attribute for button after jquery .replaceWith

Tags: jquery, html

I am going bonkers trying to figure out were the heck an underscore is coming from after a jquery .replaceWith function is run.

Here is my full code and what I am doing:

I have to change a dropdown to a single input that can not be changed by the user.. Since the value and the text have to be different, I went with a button (with css I remove border and make it look like plain text).

Code that is being changed:

```
<select name="signup_status" class="form-select required" id="edit-signup-status">
<option value="1">Confirmed Registration</option>
<option value="2">Waiting List</option>
</select>
```

I am changing this after page load to:

```
 var cur_signup_status = $("#edit-signup-status option:selected").text();
    if (cur_signup_status=="Confirmed Registration"){
        $('#edit-signup-status').replaceWith('<button value="1" disabled id="edit-signup-status" class="no-bor-in" name="signup_status">'+cur_signup_status+'</button>');
    } else if (cur_signup_status=="Waiting List"){
        $('#edit-signup-status').replaceWith('<button value="2" disabled id="edit-signup-status" class="no-bor-in" name="signup_status">'+cur_signup_status+'</button>');
    }
```

What makes NO SENSE is I am getting this on page once the function executes:

```
<button value="1" disabled="" id="edit-signup-status" class="no-bor-in" name="_signup_status">Confirmed Registration</button>
```

Notice `name="_signup_status"` is being added to the button, yet my code says `name="signup_status"`

I have looked and looked for why this is, but can not find ANYTHING!!??

Help!

Comment: Can you create demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: You're right, as presented here, this makes no sense. And it doesn't happen in a minimal test of the same code: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/bdpGdL. Something else, not included here, has to be involved.

Comment: The only thing I don't use which could be the cause is the replaceWith() call, you could try using .html() instead to see if it's different

Comment: [Seems to work correctly here](http://jsfiddle.net/rvg4ok75/).

Comment: You're making that very complicated. Create your button outside of the `if` and, within the `if` just set the appropriate value. Or use a ternary operator to set the appropriate value in the button's creation, given that's the only difference (apart from the text, which you're setting in the same way in both cases).

Comment: I guess I did not add, this is on a drupal site.. I have no idea if drupal is somehow doing this? Also, I understand the fiddle is working, but I have done nothing different then what my question asked, and I am getting an underscore.